# get map<Column,ValueOfTheColumn> from a sql query (C# MVC5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a C# method that returns perfectly a sql string query (unknown columns + unknown table + unknown conditions).

How can I get a map  as a result of executing the query ?

Thank you.

### Edit

(copied from an OP's answer, which should not have been an answer by Shnugo)

Guys sorry if that is not clear enough, I mean having as a result : `KeyValuePair<string, string>`

- the first string is the column name or the alias,
- the second string is the value returned from the query

I don't know what is the table, the columns on SQL, it's a method that generate the query, I'm trying to build something dynamic.

I hope that's more clear.

Comment: Please tag your question with the proper RDBMS (product and version). The tag `sql` is not enough...

Comment: Ok, tagged with sql-server-2008, Thank you

Comment: It's impossible to answer this. What do you even mean by `map`? The SQL Server version doesn't actually matter with such a vague question.

Comment: Why don't you use whatever library you have to execute queries to load the data? A DataTable is a dictionary of columns and values. EF, LINQ, Dapper can all execute raw queries and either map the results to concrete or `dynamic` objects

Comment: @Powerwave, I just updated first your question, then my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server you have two approaches

- [sp_describe_first_result_set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx)
- `FOR XML RAW, XMLDATA` or `XMLSCHEMA`

Try this

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT * FROM sys.objects';
```

or

```
SELECT  TOP 0 * FROM sys.objects FOR XML RAW,XMLSCHEMA
```

or

```
SELECT  TOP 0 * FROM sys.objects FOR XML RAW,XMLDATA
```

### UPDATE

Your edit told me, that you are trying to create a list of *Key-Value-Pairs* out of an unknown table / query result.

One approach is to create an XML result and use the XMLs great abilities to deal with generic structures:

In this case the unknown query is `SELECT * FROM sys.objects`. To be able to know, to which row a *KVP* belongs, there must be a *RowKey*:

```
SELECT r.value('@RowKey','nvarchar(max)') AS RowKey
      ,attr.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS ColumnName
      ,attr.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS ColumnValue
FROM
(
SELECT 
    (
    SELECT o.object_id AS RowKey
           ,* 
    FROM sys.objects AS o 
    FOR XML RAW,TYPE
    ) 
) AS TableRows(InXML)
CROSS APPLY TableRows.InXML.nodes('/row') AS A(r)
CROSS APPLY A.r.nodes('@*') AS B(attr)
```

The (partial) result

```
Key ColumnName          ColumnValue
3   RowKey              3
3   name                sysrscols
3   object_id           3
3   schema_id           4
3   parent_object_id    0
3   type                S 
3   type_desc           SYSTEM_TABLE
[many more]
```

### Warning

Whatever you are trying to achieve: *KVP*-solutions tend to become a severe headache... (type safety, castings, pivoting...)

Comment: How is this going to return a "c# map" (whatever that means)?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, well, you get meta data back... (column names and types)

Comment: You could run the query and get a DataTable that contains the column meta and the values. Or execute a raw query with EF or Dapper or ... This is just a guessing game at this point.